# How to update main form when data from dialog is changed?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

We have a main window (MainScreen.xhtml) and a dialog box (DialogScreen.xhtml) in 2 separate files.

In MainScreen.xhtml, there is a link that calls and opens DialogScreen.xhtml. Also, there is a field called fieldA. fieldA's value is updated depending on selected value from DialogScreen.

MainScreen.xhtml sample:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.fieldA}" id="fieldA"/>
```

DialogScreen.xhtml sample:

```
<cf:autoComplete id="someId" autoCompleteList="#{someBean.listItems}">
   <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="someId"/>
</cf:autoComplete>
<p:commandLink id="setFieldA" action="{someBean.someAction}" value="set fieldA"/>
```

We tried the following but neither worked:
1. In DialogScreen.xhtml update commandLink:

```
<p:commandLink id="setFieldA" action="{someBean.someAction}" value="set fieldA"/>
   <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update=":fieldA"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

2. Update MainScreen data by updating contextrequest in MainScreenBean.java

   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":fieldA");

Both of the above fix resulted in error that :fieldA component cannot be found.
How to update the main form data when the dialog box data is changed?

Comment: Where is the "fieldA" in your files? have you forgot to give it an id??

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{bean.fieldA}" id="fieldA"/>` ?

Comment: I just forgot to put the id on the sample. Updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have two `form` in two file. Make sure your dialog in `DialogScreen.xhtml` has `appendTo="@(body)"` this attribute set. It will append the html to the `MainScreen.xhtml` page.  if your `MainScreen.xhtml` has

```
<h:form id='mainForm'>
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.fieldA}" id="fieldA"/>
</h:form>
```

you can access update that field from `DialogSceen.xhtml` by

```
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
     <p:commandLink id="setFieldA" action="{someBean.someAction}" value="set 
     fieldA"/>
       <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update=":mainForm:fieldA"/>
     </p:commandLink>
   </h:form>
```

So that means you have to put **:formId:componentId** to address any component outside of the form.